# Is this patent still legal

Tags: infringement

This product is a type of therapeutic blanket for animals.  How can I manufacture myself without patent infringement?

Comment: Hi Cheri, welcome to Ask Patents! Unfortunately, our site isn't a good match for questions like "how can I avoid infringing this patent," because to answer that, we'd need to know *everything* about the patent, and *everything* about what you'd like to do. We're better placed to help you understand the patent, but to do that, we'll need to see a link or patent number such that we can see its claims. If you can [edit] your post to include those, I'd be happy to help you work on it to make it a bit more viable. Thanks, and sorry for the confusion.